# Understanding git: the difference between clone and checkout

Tags: git, github, version-control

I'm getting a little confused about the different between `git clone` and `git checkout`. For example, I am trying to download, compile and install a C++ library called `dart`. The instructions say to run the following:

```
1. Clone the repository into a directory in your home folder:

git clone git://github.com/dartsim/dart.git

2. Change directory to the DART repository and change branch to release-6.0:

cd dart
git checkout release-6.0

3. Create a build directory:

mkdir build
cd build

4. Configure and build dart:

cmake ..
make -j4
```

So am I right in thinking that `clone` actually physically downloads the source files? And that `checkout` just chooses which version of the code I want to actually work with and install?

But then what if I wanted to also install version `release-5.0`? Wouldn't the compiled libraries in the `build` directory then contain a mixture of versions 5.0 and 6.0?

And when I run `clone`, does it download all the files for 5.0, *and* all the files for 6.0? Isn't this quite inefficient if I only want to eve install 6.0?

Thanks!

Comment: on github itself, you can also choose a specific branch and just download those files directly from the repo page. [release5-1](https://github.com/dartsim/dart/archive/release-5.1.zip)  and [release6.1](https://github.com/dartsim/dart/archive/release-6.1.zip)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So am I right in thinking that clone actually physically downloads the source files?

Yes

> And that checkout just chooses which version of the code I want to actually work with and install?

Work with, yes. It updates your filesystem to reflect the state the repository was in at the time of the commit/branch you're checking out.

> But then what if I wanted to also install version release-5.0? Wouldn't the compiled libraries in the build directory then contain a mixture of versions 5.0 and 6.0?

<s>No, if you checkout 5.0 your filesystem will update to reflect the state of the 5.0 branch. Likewise for 6.0 and any others.</s>

If the build/ folder is ignored by git, which is most likely is, then yes.

> And when I run clone, does it download all the files for 5.0, and all the files for 6.0?

Basically what it does is it downloads the files as they currently are, and their history. So you will have one of each file and git knows what happened to each file in the history of the repository. When you checkout a different commit/branch, git updates the files to the state they were in at the time of that commit and it uses the history to do that.

You do not have many copies of the same file, if that is what you were asking.

> Isn't this quite inefficient if I only want to eve install 6.0?

May be. It could very well be that the 6.0 branch is branched off of the 5.0 branch and depends on its commits.